# Herbert Amann Analysis vs Zorich Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I was looking for a good analysis book and saw Analysis I by Herbert Amann which, from what I understand, introduces stuff in a very "general" sense, giving it a top-down approach. My alternative was the Mathematical Analysis books by Vladimir Zorich. I was just wondering which would give me a better foundation for future work.

Answer (score 3):

I was interested in this question, too, but also nowhere found a direct answer to it, except on a german website called [matheplanet](https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/reviews.php?op=showcontent&id=253) (you may translate the reviews/comments).

But I can tell you something from my experience with the original german edition of this book. As you start working with it, there will be moments where you want to quit and start looking for other books. And if you do so, you will immediately experience, that most of the other books are not self-contained as they claim to be, and that you WANT to see the same rigor as in Amann but you won't. So in the end you will jump back to Amann.

Most people claim, that this should not be your first book in Analysis. But the author says, it is an **introduction** to Analysis and if you master these 3 volumes, you will be equipped for most of modern mathematics.

Comment: Hi there -- thanks very much for this helpful post. I am interested in self-studying Amann-Escher but am worried about the lack of solution manual (for both unfortunately). If you had any opinions or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. The alternative would be Zorich which, it seems, doesn't have a manual either! Thanks for your time.